# Unable to access Django site from browser though there are url patterns

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, localhost

I'm trying to setup a Django site. I was able to add path in urls.py file. 
I was able to run the project using `python manage.py runserver` and see it running in console.

But when I hit the url `127.0.0.1:8000` in the browser, it's giving me **404** error.

I tried adding `"*"` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. But no use.
When I tried adding `"*.*"`, it's throwing error:

> DisallowedHost at / Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8000'. You
>   may need to add '127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

I'm getting the same error even after adding `["127.0.0.1", "localhost"]`.

I don't have any issue with firewall too. Is there anything that I'm missing that's causing this issue?